# js files are loading in unreadable format

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I was working on a Web App. I used a "✗" UTF-8 character as a delete button. Eclipse asked me to save file in UTF-8 format i told yes. Everything worked fine. But next day when i ran the app again it is throwing exception `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"`. When i checked it, all javascript file is loading in unreadable format. See image below.

[image: Screen shot of Chrome console]

I tried to replace that character with its UNICODE "&#10007;" and saved all js files in default encoding, but didn't help.

Do anyone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you saved in a different text format than you loaded it and/or loaded it in a different text format that you saved it. Without recommending a tool, I would see if you can use something to change the code-page/text-format and then try stuff.

However, seeing as what you are showing on teh screen is 3rd part stuff, you could just more easily re-download it where you got it the first time, or perhaps unpack it if you saved the installer/zip-file.

Comment: I am not downloading anything, app is running on local server.

Comment: Chances are you either can use the same software to undo the changes. Alternatively, if you keep a repo, you could roll it back, but if you don't have a repo then it would be easier to redownload the 3rd party code from their trusted sites, and then rewrite any of your own code.

It sounds like you converted it from a 8bit codepage to a 16bit code page, or more specifically it's an 8bit codepage, but being read as 16bit (meaning instead of reading 'AA' as 65 and 65 (41 in hex) it would read 0x4141 as a single character. To solve this you could try (backup first) removing the BOM with hexeditor